# Can you find an array element that starts with a string in bash?

Tags: bash

I have an array that's like this:

```
example = /home/user/example/example
other = /usr/bin/example
```

The array will change over time (the final script is going to download a file that contains the array)
Now, I need to find let's say example. I'd like the script to give me the element index (0). The script should search for an element that starts with example, as the path could change in the future.
Sorry if this isn't clear but TL:DR I want my script to give me the element index of an element that starts with a specified string.
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: That's not an array, that's two lines. Is every line an element of the array?

Comment: Hi, it's an array. I just wrote it like that. Every line is an element, correct.

Comment: If you are writing a shell script and using a file, have you considered using something like `awk` or `grep` to find the pattern on the line?

Comment: Could you write it like an bash array definition `array=("something" ..)`? Please show some code. If you have to array in your program, you can do `declare -p arrayname` and post the output. What have you tried? Do you know how to iterate over array with indexes? Iiterate over it, check if the element contains what you want and print it's index. With what specific part are you having problem with? `Can you find an array..` yes, you can.

Comment: Hi Richard! Thanks so much for pointing me at the right direction. I'll try that now.

Comment: Hi Kamil! array=("example - /home/user/example/example", "other - /usr/bin/example") I have searched the internet but I didn't find any solutions. I'm quite new at bash scripting. I have a problem with finding the element index by just specifying the first string (example), as the first string won't change, while the rest of the element (the path) can change later on.

Comment: @Botched: I have the impression that this is the situation: *"I would like to solve a problem and I think that an array is a good way to solve my problem, but I'm having some issues, so I'm focussing on how to solve the issue."*, while the real problem is maybe the fact that an array is not a good choice. What's your original problem?

Comment: :) I'm importing the file to an array, then checking if example exists in the array, then the program would have to see what index it is. The second part, checking if example exists pointed me towards an array.

Comment: @Please post the code you already have. What you have posted is simply an invocation of commands (executable files) named `example` and `other`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the indices of the array (`${!arr[@]}`). Use a pattern on the right hand side of the `[[ ... == ... ]]`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
arr=('example = /home/user/example/example'
     'other = /usr/bin/example')

find=example
unset index
for i in ${!arr[@]} ; do
    if [[ ${arr[i]} == "$find ="* ]] ; then
        index=$i
        break
    fi
done
echo $index
```

Comment: Hmm, that gave me no output when I use the array that is created from file, but it works in yours. This is in the file, after 1.0.7 there is a newline: 
example - example-file = server/binaries/main/example/1.0.7
example2 - other

Comment: To read the file I use readarray file < arr

Comment: Works for me that way, too. Do the input lines start with a leading whitespace?

Comment: Hmm, weird. The lines in the file don't start with a whitespace, but when I echo the array out after reading it the 2nd line has a whitespace!?

Comment: Show the code, maybe show the `xxd` of the input, too. Update your question with the details.